# How can i inherit view in odoo such that if i change something to 1st view it should not affect other view or if it works vice versa?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

**I have view a and b such that b is inherited from a. Now if i changes something in it should not affect a. Is it possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to set inheritance mode to `primary` like so:

```xml
<field name="mode">primary</field>
```

Default mode is `extension` and it causes original view to be modified. Mode `primary` makes a copy without modifying original view.

Example of usage:

```xml
<record id="view_crm_lead_form_mobile" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.view_crm_lead_form" />
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="phone" position="after">
            <field name="mobile"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

More on the topic:

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/field-name-mode-primary-field-can-anyone-explain-the-purpose-of-this-104612